# Create a class to populate page in ruby 1.8.7

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-1.8.7

I'm trying to make a class to populate a deals tab on my website.

Part 1. Take an items close date (CatalogItem.close_date) and use all items within 12 hours of closing.  Part 2. Calculate the deal percentage by using the current price (CatalogItem.current_price) and  estimated value (Item.estimated_price) <-- You'll notice they're in different tables but they're identified by an identical item_id.

I'm green in RoR, so I'm having  trouble connecting this in a class, but I can make it work individually in the console:

```
hour_diff = (CatalogItem.last.close_date - Time.now) / 1.hour
deal_percentage = (CatalogItem.last.current_price.to_f / Item.last.estimated_price)*100
```

As you can see I'm using my .last piece of data, but I want to create an array that runs through all my items, that's where my knowledge goes dry, any help would be much apreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using a belongs_to, but I think what you want to do is use 
an instance method.  This would be your model, app/models/catalog_item.rb

```
class CatalogItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item

  def hours_remaining
    (close_date - Time.now) / 1.hour
  end

  def deal_percentage
    (current_price.to_f / item.estimated_price)*100
  end
end
```

Then, you could access them in a view something like this:

```
<table>
  <% CatalogItem.all.each do |ci| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= ci.hours_remaining %></td>
      <td><%= ci.deal_percentage %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: .last would just be the last data entered, I was just using that in the console to pull some data.  I'd need to run against all data in the those tables and since the estimated price is in a different table wouldn't that muck this approach?

Comment: I revised my answer for you.  You can pull all records into an array with CatalogItem.all.

Comment: Pulling data from multiple tables is fine, and happens in just about every app.  Rails handles it well.  However, if these tables really represent the same object, it would probably be better to make one model and table.

Comment: I actually eneded up doing most this in sql, WAAY faster!